# How to update null records in JSON

Tags: apex, json, replace

I'm currently working on the below JSON. Sometimes records in matches return null, instead of record. And null will appear anywhere within the array

```
{
    "status": "success",

    "error_code": null,

    "matches": [

     {

      "status": "success",

      "error_code": null,

     }
      ,null,

     {}]

}
```

Apex code:

```
if(jsonResponse.contains(',null,'))

{

  jsonResponse =  jsonResponse.replaceAll(',null,', ',{"id": ""},');

}

if(jsonResponse.contains('null\\,{'))

{ 

  jsonResponse =  jsonResponse.replaceAll('null\\,{', '{"id": ""},{');

}

if(jsonResponse.contains('null\\]'))

{            

   jsonResponse =  jsonResponse.replaceAll('null\\]', '{"id": ""}]');

}
```

Please guide me on how to replace null with array #Json #Apex #Trailhead

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this instead of manipulating the string directly:

```
Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonResponse);

List<Object> matches = (List<Object>) data.get('matches');

for(Integer i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++) {
    if(matches[i] == null) {
        matches[i] = new Map<String, String>{'id' => ''};
    }
}

data.put('matches', matches);
String newJsonResponse = JSON.serialize(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not manipulate the string. Deserialize it and remove the null from the list.

The first step is define a custom Apex class to map that response, then you can leverage [typed deserialization](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_deserialize), finally you can loop over the list of matches and remove null objects

```java
ResultWrapper result = (ResultWrapper) JSON.deserialize(jsonResponse, ResultWrapper.class);
if (result.matches != null) {
    for (Integer i = result.matches.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        // remove both null and empty objects
        if (result.matches[i] == null || String.isBlank(result.matches[i].status)) {
            result.matches.remove(i);
            // here you could add a new object at the same position if you want
        }
    }
}
System.debug(result);
```

Comment: I've tried a similar approach but my code is failing with a null exception because the system is excepting an array record but null is there.

Comment: @Pavantej please provide more detail (the actual code) about the null pointer exception, so I could help with the debug/fix. Anyway in my code I checked for the possible null value based on the question's code.

Answer (score -2):

```
public class Match {
    public String status;
    public String error_code;
}

public class JsonResponse {
    public String status;
    public String error_code;
    public List<Match> matches;
}

public static void replaceNullMatches(String jsonString) {
    JsonResponse response = (JsonResponse) JSON.deserialize(jsonString, JsonResponse.class);
    
    for (Integer i = 0; i < response.matches.size(); i++) {
        if (response.matches[i] == null) {
            Match defaultMatch = new Match();
            defaultMatch.status = 'default_status';
            defaultMatch.error_code = 'default_error';
            response.matches[i] = defaultMatch;
        }
    }

    // If you want to get updated JSON string back:
    String updatedJsonString = JSON.serialize(response);
    System.debug(updatedJsonString);
}

String jsonString = '{ "status": "success", "error_code": null, "matches": [ { "status": "success", "error_code": null }, null, {} ] }';
replaceNullMatches(jsonString);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).